# Open port for outbound and inbound traffic

Tags: security, tcp, port, firewall

I want to send push notifications to devices through the Apple push service server (APNS). Now the APNS requires an unproxied connection to them with some ports open.

To quote Apple from this link - Push providers, iOS devices, and Mac computers are often behind firewalls. To send notifications, you will need to allow inbound and outbound TCP packets over port 2195.

Now the security team is asking why we need to open both inbound and outbound when we will only sending (outwards) the request to APNS.

Now I am no networking guy. My basic web brain tells me we will be sending a POST request (outwards as seen from my server) to APNS, and this POST request will have a response. For this response, I will need to open inbound traffic for that same port i.e. 2195. Am i right?

Answer (score 1):

I think your network is using Statefull/ZBF (Zone Based Firewall). for getting the response of a request you need to open both inbound and outbound requests. the firewall for this port should configured on "Inspection" that lets both inbound and outbound traffic.

Comment: thanks for your answer.. i hope you got my point..if i dont open for inbound traffic, will the whole POST request fail?

Comment: i researched more..i dont think u r correct..inbound is for allowing others to connect..outbound is for allowing the computer to connect to network

Comment: hi lakhshay, in network inbound and outbound are defined for your network boundary. actually its from your network's boundary perspective. so the traffic that comes in your network is inbound  , and the traffic that goes out is outbound. i think i got your point now, for POST  you need to open outbound traffic, but POST request isn't an outbound request, it contains DNS query before that (if your using URL), and beside of that, there is a three-way handshake connection in TCP connections that its unique for every connections (ports). so your answer is yes, you should open it for both sites.

Comment: thi picture may help you : [link](http://https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/TNBlogsFS/prod.evol.blogs.technet.com/CommunityServer.Blogs.Components.WeblogFiles/00/00/01/02/59/Port%20filter.png) that is a three-way hand shake from a client with port 40052 to a server with port 25 (SMTP) .